# Concurrently Run `watch` & `nodemon` with Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, watch, jshint, nodemon

I'm just getting started with Grunt and would like to run `grunt-contrib-watch` [[GitHub page]](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to lint my JavaScript every time a file is modified (with `grunt-contrib-jshint` [[GitHub page]](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint)) and run `grunt-nodemon` [[GitHub page]](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon) too, concurrently using `grunt-concurrent` [[GitHub page]](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent).

As I understand (which I evidently don't) my Gruntfile should:

1. Run `concurrent` by default
2. `concurrent` runs `watch`
3. `watch` runs `jshint` every time a file is modified

`Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        concurrent: {
            dev: [
                'watch'
            ],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            server: [
                '**/*.js',
                '!node_modules/**/*.js'
            ],
            options: {
                node: true
            }
        },
        watch: {
            all: [
                '**/*/.js',
                '!node_modules/**/*.js'
            ],
            tasks: [
                'jshint'
            ]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'concurrent:dev'/*,
        'jshint',
        'watch'*/
    ]);
};

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'concurrent:dev'
    ]);
};
```

N.B. I've not added `grunt-nodemon` into the mix yet.

It looks like `concurrent` is running `watch` but when I modify a file it appears `jshint` isn't running. I certainly don't get any output in the Terminal (I thought `logConcurrentOutput: true` does this).

Here is the output I get in the Terminal:

```
Running "concurrent:dev" (concurrent) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...    


Done, without errors.
```

I would also like to run `jshint` when I first run the `default` task (as well as when I modify files).

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `watch` task exits if there are no files found to 'watch'; as per [this issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/183).

To easily tell `watch` to watch the same files as the `jshint` task I used Grunt's templating engine to reference the same `Array` of files as the `jshint` task.

I then added `jshint` to the list of concurrent tasks to run so it would be ran initially and as I modify files (with `watch`).

Here is my working `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        concurrent: {
            dev: [
                'jshint',
                'watch'
            ],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            server: [
                '**/*.js',
                '!node_modules/**/*.js'
            ],
            options: {
                node: true
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: '<%= jshint.server %>',
            tasks: [
                'jshint'
            ]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'concurrent'
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an Express server then you can use [grunt-express-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-express-server). The documentation has a good guide on using this with JSHINT, and LiveReload + Watch/Regarde.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'public/javascripts/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
    },
    watch: {
      express: {
        files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.ejs'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'express:dev'],
        options: {
          spawn: false
        }
      }
    },
    express: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: './app.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('server', [ 'express:dev', 'watch' ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonathon you need to check that your globbing pattern actually matches any files. As the link to the issue suggests you can try the `nonull` option. I would also suggest to run grunt with the flag `--debug` so you can see more of what's happening under the hood.

[This is a working Gruntfile](https://gist.github.com/thanpolas/7182266) which launches a node server, watches for changes and livereloads. It uses the [grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express) plugin.